# Show/Hide php button from another PHP page?

Tags: php

I have two php pages. One is where I display the buttons and another where I perform operations.
The first PHP page, I am hiding the button and the script is given below :

```
<p>
        <td><a href="Button.php" target="_blank"><button  id="Button" name="Button" download style="visibility: hidden" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pdf"" aria-hidden="true"></i>Click Here</button></a></td>
</p>
```

I have a second php page which gets triggered via another button. From this script I want to show the button in First page. How do I do it?

Second.php

```
<?php
...
...
?>
```

Comment: `if(condition){...} else{...}`.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner But how do I activate the button from Second Script? i do not know how to do this.

Comment: You can use sessions or cookies if you can and want to. Sessions would be better than cookies.